# JavaScript/userscript: Get redirect url of GET request that redirects to url blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm writing a userscript for **site a**. There is a link to a different route on **site a** that redirects to a route on **site b**. So long as I am logged in on **site a**, the redirect works. I need to send the redirect url (**site b**) to a server of mine. I need to get the url from the userscript so the redirect works.

Using $.ajax to hit the link with a GET request, i get this error in my console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'site b/route' (redirected from 'site a/link route') from origin 'site a' has been blocked by CORS policy...
```

I don't need the content from the redirect on **site b**, I only need the url. I've tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'site a/link route',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ 
        console.log(data); // this will not run due to CORS
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // this runs, but can i get the redirect url (site b)?
    }
});
```

Is it possible to get the redirect url? Would it be possible to use XMLHttpRequest to do this?

Edit: I've all but given up on this. I found another solution that uses an extension and isn't relevant to this question at all. If this question gets new answers/comments I'll still try to find a working answer.

Comment: You could try using your server as proxy to make the request server to server

Comment: @charlietfl I've done that for other scripts but unfortunately I need to be logged into site a for it to redirect in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not completely possible with XMLHttpRequest. Normally, CORS is not allowed aside from within the origin. This is done on the server side  and is important in [cyber security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: I don't need to actually make the request to site b. Is getting the url that would be blocked by CORS still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy,

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
```

On your code, you can do something like this,

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + 'site a/link route',
type: 'GET',
success: function(data){ 
    console.log(data); // this will not run due to CORS
},
error: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // this runs, but can i get the redirect url (site b)?
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
From cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com:
"Cookies are disabled and stripped from requests."
The "site a link route" only redirects when logged in, so this solution won't work.